# Finding parameter for quadratic equation

Tags: quadratics, parametric

> Given $x^2 - 3ax + a^2 = 0$  and 
>   $$\frac{x_1^4-x_2^4}{\sqrt{5}x_1x_2} + x_1 + x_2 -20x_1x_2 - 4 = 0$$
>   Find $a$.

The answer is $1$ ($a = 1$)

I tried to present $x_1^4 - x_2^4$ as $(x_1+x_2)(x_1-x_2)(x_1+x_2)^2-2x_1x_2$ But I can't replace (x1-x2)

Note: $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the roots of the equation.

Comment: Is it $x_2^3$ ? are you sure?

Comment: It's 4 I made a mistake.

Comment: Is it $\sqrt {5}x_1+x_2$ or $\sqrt{5} (x_1+x_2)$?

Comment: Its $\sqrt{5}*x1*x2$

Comment: Then the problem is trivial

Comment: How do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the factorisation, 
$$(x_1^4-x_2^4)=(x_1+x_2)(x_1-x_2)(x_1^2+x_2^2)$$
We get 
$$(x_1^4-x_2^4)=(3a)[\sqrt{(x_1+x_2)^2-4x_1x_2}](9a^2-2a^2)$$
$$\implies (x_1^4-x_2^4)=21a^3\sqrt{5}a$$
Can you continue?

Comment: Although I was able to finish the exercise with the provided information, I'm having trouble with understanding how you managed to get $(3a)[\sqrt{(x_1+x_2)^2-4x_1x_2}](9a^2-2a^2)$ , from $(x_1+x_2)(x_1-x_2)(x_1^2+x_2^2)$Obviously $(x_1 + x_2)$ becomes $3a$ from Viet's formulas, but I'm lost on the other part.

Comment: Try simplifying the thing inside the square root, it becomes $x_1-x_2$, And $(x_1^2+x_2^2)=(x_1+x_2)^2-2x_1x_2$